# After publishing the asp.net core 2.2 app to azure app its returning 500

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to publish an app to azure app service but the problem i'm getting is http 307 status which is for temporary redirection.
In my startup.cs i've already configured the app to use SSL port 443.
but after checking logs i'm getting.

```
2020-02-05 09:15:00.1616|INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost|Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://appservicenameabc.azurewebsites.net/  
2020-02-05 09:15:00.1778|WARN|Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware|Failed to determine the https port for redirect.
2020-02-05 09:15:00.4230|ERROR|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware|An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
2020-02-05 09:15:00.4403|ERROR|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware|An exception was thrown attempting to execute the error handler.
2020-02-05 09:15:00.4554|ERROR|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpServer|Connection ID "15996785878030621091", Request ID "800019a8-0000-de00-b63f-84710c7967bb": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
2020-02-05 09:15:00.5086|INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost|Request finished in 347.65ms 500
```

My startup.cs look like this

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
           //other code removed
            services.AddHsts(options =>
            {
                options.Preload = true;
                options.IncludeSubDomains = true;
                options.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(60);
            });

            services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
            {
                options.HttpsPort=443;
                options.RedirectStatusCode = StatusCodes.Status307TemporaryRedirect;
            });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
}
```

As specified by error message i added 443 port in the services.AddHttpsRedirection() method. I also tried specifying the https_port in appsettings.json.

**Edit**: When i removed google authentication its working fine. I also ran the project in production mode locally there i'm seeing its unable to find the CliendId for google auth. But the Id is present in UserSecrets.Json

Here is the code i commented. Google auth is working locally.

```
            //services.AddAuthentication()
            //    .AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
            //        {
            //            googleOptions.ClientId = Configuration.GetSection("Google")["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
            //            googleOptions.ClientSecret = Configuration.GetSection("Google")["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
            //        });
```

Comment: Make sure your code handles all exceptions. The service will terminate your app for unhandled exceptions. That will also help you pinpoint where the error is.

Comment: same error even after putting the try catch block

Comment: What do you mean the same error? If you caught the exception and handled it the error would not be passed to the service.

Comment: by same I mean 500 error.

Answer (score 1):

Your port 443 is probably occupied.

Comment: only port 443 for HTTPS and 80 for HTTP is available.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related to UserSecrets.Json since it was not available in the production so when i was trying to add google authentication it was throwing error.
As suggested by @John Hanley when i added try catch i got the iishttpserver error.
Which was coming due to client id and client secret was unable to found on.
So i added the client id and client secrets to the appsettings.json

so after following MSDN i came to know that UserSecrets.json is available only in development.